# Encrypted Install of Ubuntu on a SSD and SSD Support for Encryption / Performance

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, ssd

I am looking to purchase a SSD to use as the primary drive on my computer, with the goal of installing Ubuntu (or Linux Mint) with an encrypted hard drive install for security purposes.

There's a variety of SSDs on the market now which make mention they can support AES-256 encryption, which could potentially improve the performance when encrypted.

- Does the encryption support work effectively / would it make a difference?
- Are there specific SSDs that would be suited to the installer encryption offered with Ubuntu and variants of (Linux Mint, Xubuntu, etc)?
- Are there any important settings or anything to keep in mind when using a encrypted SSD with Ubuntu?
- Any required components, hardware or settings to prolong / improve performance or security? Or to make use of the encryption support the SSD offers?

I've looked at a few sources of information covering TRIM, though always interested if there's some other pieces of wisdom people are happy to share.

Thanks for your time everybody.

Comment: See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53872/how-do-i-set-up-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ssd?rq=1) question.