# How do I utilize hardware-based encryption on an SSD?

Tags: encryption

Some SSDs support hardware disk encryption. How should I set up Ubuntu to take advantage of it?

There are [guides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53872/how-do-i-set-up-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ssd) on setting up Full Disk Encryption, but it is unclear to me whether hardware acceleration gets used.

Comment: @Nmath Example: 'AES 256-bit encryption' ([Crucial MX500](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/storage-ssd-mx500)), 'AES 128 bit' ([Intel 520 series](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/66248/intel-ssd-520-series-120gb-2-5in-sata-6gb-s-25nm-mlc.html)). I have personally installed Ubuntu on the latter, but I'm not sure whether hardware accelerated encryption gets used.

Comment: @Nmath some SSDs (and HDDs) have on-board controllers with support for AES-256 encryption. However, these are typically very proprietary and require the Windows drivers to use as such, IIRC. Such as https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/how-to-enable-disk-encryption-on-samsung-evo-ssd-hard-drive/ But real technical details are few and far between.

Comment: You may want to also see https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/you-cant-trust-bitlocker-to-encrypt-your-ssd-on-windows-10/ on why it's probably better to use the OS-side full disk encryption rather than hardware encryption. Manufacturers have consistently failed to disclose how encryption is actually implemented, so the probability that it's done wrong is pretty high.